# Problem with Android togglebutton

Tags: android

I tried to set up my togglebutton properties layout using style.xml.
Here's my code:

```
    <ToggleButton android:id="@+id/button_toggle_1" style="button_test_1"/>

    <ToggleButton android:id="@+id/button_toggle_2"
        android:textOff="test2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ToggleButton android:id="@+id/button_toggle_3" style="button_test_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

For ID=button_toggle_1, I apply a style (style.xml), here's the code:

```
<style name="button_test_1">
    <item name="android:textOff">test1</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
</style>

<style name="button_test_3">
    <item name="android:textOff">test3</item>
</style>
```

I can see button 2 and 3 but the text for button 3 is different from what I set it to be. button 3 text = "APAGADO". From this test, I conclude that togglebutton simply cannot set its properties using style.xml. Is this true? or did I do something wrong?

If toggle button is "special", anyone knows the reason why? is this "special" condition applies to other things as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not referencing the styles correctly. It is `style="@style/style_name"`. [See documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html).

Comment: Thanks! Believe it or not, I got all my other referencing correct except for these togglebutton. Anyway, I've tested this on N1 and it works perfectly. Thanks again.